# Why is a new 16550 $4?

Tags: serial

I can't imagine that the 16550 hasn't made back its design costs by a factor of at least 10 by now, why does it cost $4.32 in quantity? That makes no sense. 
http://www.ti.com/product/PC16550D/samplebuy

Comment: Because of [economics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supply_and_demand).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about price-forming factors in economics.

Comment: See the "LIFEBUY" designation on most of the options? Very little stock on those that are still active? Nobody is designing this part into new volume designs, it's on the way out. So the price goes up.

Comment: *That makes no sense.* What makes you think that **you** know more about pricing of ICs than the people at TI who have basically invented the IC?

Comment: Low demand for a 40 yr old part.

Comment: If you're looking for alternatives - you can probably implement your own UART on any of several cheap microcontrollers or CPLDs these days. And a great many microcontrollers have built-in UARTs so you don't need one. I'm guessing this is for a retrocomputing project?

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure the volume sold is very low; it's also a physically large device that requires old tech to manufacture.